# Coming IN \ FROM the opposite direction

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, prepositional-phrases

Macmillan dictionary says:

> The car smashed into a lorry coming **in the opposite direction.**

If I use:

> .... coming **from the opposite direction.**

Is there any difference?

Comment: It is good that you mentioned the dictionary. Ideally, you add the link to the page, so people can find it faster (edit the question). Thank you.

Comment: "From" has several usages which are mentioned [here](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/from). What you are looking for is likely to be the usage #4, but you can see why "from" would still fail to make a suitable alternative.

Comment: @TasneemZh: the problem is not "from" in itself, but its association with "come" and "direction". However, "**going** in the opposite direction" would be a different story. Or?

Comment: Do you mean "... the problem is not "in" in itself..."?

Answer (score 1):

The meanings of "in" and "from" in this context are very similar.  Using "from" is a typical meaning of "from".

You can consider "coming in the opposite direction" to be an idiom. You can't generalise it to say "a car coming in London"  (but "from London" would be fine).

You can say "in the direction of London". And this can be used with "going" to indicate a direction.

In the idiomatic use "coming in the opposite direction" is correct and natural, and has the same meaning as "coming from the opposite direction".

Answer (score -2):

I would use:

> ... coming **from** the opposite direction.

without any hesitation. Until now, it did not even occur to me that **in** can be used in this context. While it might be OK in some sense, it is unnatural.

---

An alternative using "in" and sound proper is:

> The car smashed into a lorry **going / traveling** in the opposite direction.

---

On a different note, the people at Macmillan dictionary have a very original way of seeing the world. I mean, they must be able to see sound waves, right?

[image: View the pronunciation]

Comment: Would you please care to explain your downvote?

Comment: I don't know why you'd characterize this as "unnatural". [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coming+in+the+opposite+direction%2Ccoming+from+the+opposite+direction&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3) would indicate that both expressions are idiomatic.