# "View the pronunciation"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

While studying for [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/202402/89027), I found something else which troubles me.

[The page](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/opposite_1) for that word ("opposite", or for any other word), they have a link called "View the pronunciation":

[image: View the pronunciation]

Now my big curiosity is: **is it possible to see / view pronunciations? In English or in any other language?**

To the best of my knowledge, pronunciation is about sound waves, and view is about electromagnetic waves. Unless having some rare brain condition, one cannot see sounds and one cannot hear images.

> NOTE: I am **not** talking about viewing pronunciation *rules, transcriptions, depictions, pages with information* etc. I am strictly curious about **that** specific message. Also, I am not talking about "Listen to recording of pronunciation" or any other **intended** meanings.

**Bottom line:** is it some rule / exception stating that it is possible to **view the pronunciation**? I think it is totally incorrect but hey! it is in a dictionary, right?!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to view pronunciation, by using [Phonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonics).
Actually, in English language, Letters, Greek symbols or Digraphs are used to depict different phoneme (distinct sounds). Each letter or symbol represents a special kind of sound, thus by reading/viewing those, one can know how to pronounce the word.

Comment: Yes, but letters are **depictions** of pronunciation, but not pronunciation. I called them "transcriptions" in my question. I am talking about the most strict interpretation of the text. Of course, I understand what they want, but I do not understand their English, especially being a dictionary!! :)

Comment: The example link goes to a page that shows a symbolic representation of the word's pronunciation.  That page has a link to an audio file.  Below the link to the audio file is a note that the user can "Click to listen to the pronunciation of **opposite**."

Comment: @virolino Lets assume the dictionary uses the words "view the pronunciation" metaphorically ;)

Comment: How can one learn a language, if the dictionaries use metaphors instead of definitions?! :))  Nonetheless, I appreciate your political correctness. ;)

Comment: @Jasper: that is the **intended** meaning for sure. But one cannot watch an audio file, or listen to a picture. However, I agree that "View a page" is totally proper. Also, "Listen to pronunciation" is also proper. My question is about the "View the pronunciation".

Comment: You can view this when you click on that link: ˈɒpəzɪt - that is an IPA spelling of the word that tells you how to pronounce it (with a stress mark that tells you that the first syllable is stressed). I believe “pronunciation” can mean either the actual sounds you hear or a written representation of those sounds.